# Rails generate scaffold user:string password: string just creates a new rails folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin

I'm new to rails and trying to follow along with railstutorial.org.

When I use Rails generate scaffold user:string password:string, it creates a new folder entitled generate and does the same command as "Rails Demo_App".  I'm assuming I don't have something installed correctly.

I'm using Windows 7, Cygwin/Vim/Sqlite3 - I have needed to reinstall Cygwin about 3 times to make sure openssh, git, vim, and other plugins/libraries were installed.  I'm assuming I will need to do something similar again.

Also, a Gemfile isn't created with the rails command.  Could this be related?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? The command in your title is for Rails 3, as is the presence of the gemfile.

Comment: 2.3.8 - How come this tutorial I'm reading talks about rails s as a shortcut for script/server?  Is it that I don't have the newest version of rails?

Comment: Have a look at http://railstutorial.org/book?version=2.3 instead for the 2.3.8 version. Most of the command line prompts have changed considerably between rails 2 and 3 - check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html for a guide to the 2.3.8 commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you supposed to call `script/generate scaffold user:string password:string` ? AFAIK, calling `generate` not from app folder may cause incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use `script/generate scaffold ...` inside of your application directory. The `rails` command is used to create a new project.